# How to round the edges?

Tags: modeling, edges

i am following a tutorial but the guy is using maya, i realised that his mesh is more smooth than mine, even if i click smooth , my edge still looks squared and horrible, if i click smooth , then it will be weird and smaller . how to i smooth my edges like the edges from the pic bellow? can someone help?

[image: i need to smooth edges here to look like the second pic mesh]

[image: i need round lines like this]

P.S. I know i have asked so many questions and people may ask why i dont take udemy or university courses. the reason is that i'm unimployed, and it has been realy hard to get employed. so i am trying to learn something for free , my goal is to make a character for a game. Objetcs and stuff are not hard, but human body and heads is realy hard but i need to learn it.and I am very grateful for the help with my questions

Comment: Try Adding a Subdvision Surface modifier, this will add non-destructive geometric detail. if you like it you can Apply it.

Comment: Thaank you so much, it worked11!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rob told in a comment it is simply the **subdivision surface** modifier, which doesn't change the mesh.

Here is how to create the same display with blender:

[image: adding subsurf]

Comment: thanks a lot for showing me this!! it looks much better now =)!!!